# Can a C++ function be declared such that the return value cannot be ignored?

Tags: c++, return-value, void

I'm trying to determine whether a C++ function can be declared in such a way that the return value cannot be ignored (ideally detected at compile time). I tried to declare a class with a `private` (or in C++11, `delete`d) `operator void()` to try to catch the implicit conversion to void when a return value is unused.

Here's an example program:

```
class Unignorable {
    operator void();
};

Unignorable foo()
{
    return Unignorable();
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, my compiler (clang-703.0.31) says:

```
test.cpp:2:5: warning: conversion function converting 'Unignorable' to 'void' will never be used
    operator void();
    ^
```

and doesn't raise any error or warning on the call to `foo()`. So, that won't work. Is there any other way to do this? Answers specific to C++11 or C++14 or later would be fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692892/force-returned-object-to-be-assigned

Comment: Are you positive that there's a implicit conversion to `void`? I can't find anything in the standard about it. (But I'm not even sure what would be converted.) AFAIK, all that happens when the return value has no "receiver" is the construction and destruction of a temporary object.

Comment: C++17 will have the [`[[nodiscard]]` attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) for this purpose.

Comment: [You can mimic that in pre-c++17](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Exploding_Return_Type), the references in the wiki write to std::err, but you can always throw an exception.

Comment: Related: [g++ How to get warning on ignoring function return value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2870529/514235) ... and ... [force returned object to be assigned](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12692892/514235)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To summarize from other answers & comments, basically you have 3 choices:

1. Get C++17 to be able to use  `[[nodiscard]]`
2. In g++ (also clang++), use compiler extensions like `__wur` (defined
   as `__attribute__ ((__warn_unused_result__))`), or the more portable (C++11 and up only) `[[gnu::warn_unused_result]]` attribute.
3. Use runtime checks to catch the problem during unit testing

---

If all of these 3 are not possible, then there is one more way, which is kind of **"Negative compiling"**. Define your `Unignorable` as below:

```
struct Unignorable {
  Unignorable () = default;
#ifdef NEGATIVE_COMPILE
  Unignorable (const Unignorable&) = delete;  // C++11
  Unignorable& operator= (const Unignorable&) = delete;
  //private: Unignorable (const Unignorable&); public:  // C++03
  //private: Unignorable& operator= (const Unignorable&); public: // C++03
  /* similar thing for move-constructor if needed */
#endif
};
```

Now compile with `-DNEGATIVE_COMPILE` or equivalent in other compilers like MSVC. It will give errors at wherever the result *is Not ignored*:

```
auto x = foo();  // error
```

However, it will not give any error wherever the result *is ignored*:

```
foo(); // no error
```

Using any modern code browser (like eclipse-cdt), you may find all the occurrences of `foo()` and fix those places which didn't give error. In the new compilation, simply remove the pre-defined macro for "NEGATIVE_COMPILE".

This might be bit better compared to simply finding `foo()` and checking for its return, because there might be many functions like `foo()` where you may not want to ignore the return value.

This is bit tedious, but will work for all the versions of C++ with all the compilers.

Answer (score 7):

Prior to c++17 this approach came to mind:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

// proxy object which complains if it still owns the return
// value when destroyed
template<class T>
struct angry
{
  angry(T t) : value_(std::move(t)) {} 
  angry(angry&&) = default;
  angry(angry const&) = default;
  angry& operator=(angry&&) = default;
  angry& operator=(angry const&) = default;

  ~angry() noexcept(false)
  {
    if (value_) throw std::logic_error("not used");
  } 

  T get() && { 
    T result = std::move(value_).value();
    value_.reset();
    return result; 
  }

  boost::optional<T> value_;
};

// a function which generates an angry int    
angry<int> foo()
{
  return 10;
}

int main()
{
  // obtain an int
  auto a = foo().get();

  // this will throw
  foo();
}
```

Synopsis: rather than return a T, a function returns an `angry<T>` which will punish the caller by throwing a `logic_error` if the value is not extracted prior to destruction.

It's a run-time solution, which is a limitation, but at least ought to be caught early in unit tests.

A canny user can of course subvert it:

```
foo().get();  // won't throw
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach and I've upvoted it but ideally I'm looking for a compile time solution. I'm not concerned about the ability for callers to subvert it, because they always can by assigning the result to something and then simply not using that value.

Comment: @GregHewgill then I think you're out of luck until c++17, barring compiler extensions

Answer (score 7):

See [__attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

```
int foo() __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result));
int foo(){return 123;}

int main()
{
    foo(); //compiler warning
    auto i = foo(); //valid
}
```

Then force the warning to be an error:

```
clang++ -std=c++1z -Werror="unused-result"
```

Comment: In G++ (probably clang++ too), we can also use `__wur` as a shorthand macro for `__attribute__ ((__warn_unused_result__))`. This macro is used after `::system(...)` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MFC , you may try ***Check_return*** before your function declaration.
See more about it on [Annotating function behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/annotating-function-behavior?view=vs-2019)